# Maximally commuting structure inside a nonabelian Lie group [SU($N$), SO($N$)]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a non-abelian compact Lie group $G$. Pick up any generator $T$ of Lie algebra of this $G$. This generator $T$ generates a U(1) subgroup inside $G$.

Question: What is the structure (group?) inside this $G$ that maximally commuting with this U(1) generated by $T$? Let us call this as a **maximally commuting structure inside $G$ respect to U(1) from $T$.**

1. What is the maximally commuting structure for $G=$SU($N$)? and for $G=$U($N$)?
2. What is the maximally commuting structure for $G=$SO($N$)? and for $G=$O($N$)?
3. What is the maximally commuting structure for $G=$Sp($N$)?

Thank you for the helps from experts!

p.s. Naively, the maximally commuting structure for $G=$SU($N$) should at least contains U(1)$^{N-1}$. But I am not sure what will it be in general.

p.s.2. please also answer the specific examples given above.

Comment: Can you be more precise by what you mean by "a generator $T$ of the Lie algebra of $G$?  Do you just any element of the Lie algebra?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Any element is good.

Comment: p.s. To count as an eligible answer, one needs to also answer the examples given above.

Answer (score 3):

The examples that interest you are simple groups. I assume the group is simply connected. The maximal commutative subgroup of a semi-simple Lie subgroup is known as the Cartan subgroup. Its algebra is the Cartan subalgebra.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Definition_of_a_Cartan_subalgebra

Comment: +1, Thanks -- great to know its a sCartan ubgroup. But it will be nice to know the group structure for the above examples as well to get some intuitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily show that it's a subgroup, at least.  Let's call it $Z_{U(1)}(G)$ for want of a better notation. Then $e\in Z_{U(1)}(G)$ is trivial, $a, b\in Z_{U(1)}(G)\implies ab\in Z_{U(1)}(G)$ is almost trivial (just move the element of $U(1)$ past each one in turn), and for $a\in Z_{U(1)}(G)\implies a^{-1}\in Z_{U(1)}(G)$, consider the element $(a^{-1}u)^{-1}$ for some $u\in U(1)$ and compare it to $(ua^{-1})^{-1}$...

**ETA:** More generally this is known as the [*centralizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of your $U(1)$ and you may be able to find more information about it under that name.

Comment: +1, Thanks -- great to know its a subgroup. But it will be nice to know the group structure for the above examples.